# How to stop key input from blocking the movement of an object drawn on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

So i have a simple html5 canvas render loop and I'm handling keydown and keyup.
A rectangle drawn on the screen can move left,right, up and down.

The problem is when you move left and right in succession, the rectangle seems to stop for a very long time, like it's being interrupted and I just want it to have a more smooth transition towards the opposite direction.
Even just changing any direction causes the rectangle to stop.

here's the Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NeuroTypicalCure/sq6czebr/39/

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('c');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;

let input = {
    key: null,
  directions: {
    up: 1.5,
    down: 0.5,
    left: 1,
    right: 2
  }
}

let player = {
    x: 0,
  y: 0,
  direction: null,
  speed: 5
}

// start
draw();

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    if(input.key === 'w'){
    player.direction = input.directions.up;
  }
  if(input.key === 's'){
    player.direction = input.directions.down;
  }
  if(input.key === 'a'){
    player.direction = input.directions.left;
  }
  if(input.key === 'd'){
    player.direction = input.directions.right;
  }

  // keyup -> speed 0 // else -> speed 5
  if(input.key === null){
    player.speed = 0;
  }else{
    player.speed = 5;
  }

  player.x += Math.cos(player.direction*Math.PI)*player.speed;
  player.y += Math.sin(player.direction*Math.PI)*player.speed;

  ctx.fillRect(player.x,player.y,50,50);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function handleKeyDown(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    input.key = e.key
}
function handleKeyUp(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    input.key = null;
}
window.addEventListener('keydown',handleKeyDown);
window.addEventListener('keyup',handleKeyUp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code lies in your handling of `keyup` events:

```
function handleKeyUp(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    input.key = null;
}
```

You're basically reseting `input.key` whenever a key is released, no matter if it's a different key than the one that initiated the move. So if you press two keys and then release one, it will reset `input.key` (until your computer sent another `keydown` event - if you're still holding down the key). This can be fixed with a simple check if the `keyup` event belongs to the current `input.key`.

```
function handleKeyUp(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.key === input.key) input.key = null;
}
```

Here's a code snippet:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('c');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;

let input = {
    key: null,
  directions: {
    up: 1.5,
    down: 0.5,
    left: 1,
    right: 2
  }
}

let player = {
    x: 0,
  y: 0,
  direction: null,
  speed: 5
}

// start
draw();

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    if(input.key === 'w'){
    player.direction = input.directions.up;
  }
  if(input.key === 's'){
    player.direction = input.directions.down;
  }
  if(input.key === 'a'){
    player.direction = input.directions.left;
  }
  if(input.key === 'd'){
    player.direction = input.directions.right;
  }

  // keyup -> speed 0 // else -> speed 5
  if(input.key === null){
    player.speed = 0;
  }else{
    player.speed = 5;
  }

  player.x += Math.cos(player.direction*Math.PI)*player.speed;
  player.y += Math.sin(player.direction*Math.PI)*player.speed;

  ctx.fillRect(player.x,player.y,50,50);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function handleKeyDown(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    input.key = e.key
}
function handleKeyUp(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.key === input.key) input.key = null;
}
window.addEventListener('keydown',handleKeyDown);
window.addEventListener('keyup',handleKeyUp);
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies with the fact that you can hold multiple keys at the same time, your logic should reflect that. i.e.:

https://jsfiddle.net/danfoord1/cr84xh2n/19/

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('c');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;

let input = {
  keys: [],
  directions: {
    up: 1.5,
    down: 0.5,
    left: 1,
    right: 2
  }
}

let player = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  directions: [],
  speed: 5
}

const directions = {
  'w': 1.5,
  's': 0.5,
  'a': 1,
  'd': 2
};

// start
draw();

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // keyup -> speed 0 // else -> speed 5
  if (input.keys.length === 0) {
    player.speed = 0;
  } else {
    player.speed = 5;
  }

  player.directions = input.keys.map(k => directions[k]);

  player.directions.forEach(d => {
    player.x += Math.cos(d * Math.PI) * player.speed;
    player.y += Math.sin(d * Math.PI) * player.speed;
  });

  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 50, 50);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function handleKeyDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (input.keys.indexOf(e.key) === -1) {
    input.keys.push(e.key);
  }
}
function handleKeyUp(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (input.keys.indexOf(e.key) > -1) {
    input.keys.splice(input.keys.indexOf(e.key), 1);
  }
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
```